# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I sometimes get this error:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019079a984 objc_object::release() + 8
1  APP                            0x000000010015a128 -[DEContext callService:service:] (DENavajoContext.m:116)
2  APP                            0x000000010015fcc4 +[DEContext(DXContext) genericServiceRequest:service:error:expectedMessage:] (DEContext+DXContext.m:31)
3  APP                            0x0000000100111a64 __28+[DXLogo logo:callback:]_block_invoke (DXLogo.m:81)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190d58014 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190d57fd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190d5f2b8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 556
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000190d5f4fc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000190eed6bc _pthread_wqthread + 356
```

I've searched SO and I found a couple things:

- I could have a dangling pointer?
- Out of memory (which I'm sure it isn't)

Now my question is how do I fix an error like this? Where do I start looking etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Zombie Objects in order to debug this. Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run Debug Section -> Diagnostics Section -> (Check) Enable Zombie Objects.

You can find some more details [here](http://pikaware.com/blog/xcode-6-debugging-exc_bad_access-runtime-memory-exception/)

Answer (score 0):

Start by figuring out how to reproduce the bug. Then start up Instruments (CMD+I in Xcode) and use the Zombie-Instrument. When the Simulator starts up, reproduce the problem and you should be able to figure out where the problem is.